# With Protractor 1.0.0 rc2 + is the browser.waitForAngular() still required?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I was watching a youtube video and in that there was an example:

```
loginPage.userName.sendKeys ...
loginPage.password.sendKeys ...
loginPage.loginButton.click();
browser.waitForAngular();
expect( ...
```

I thought Protractor was coded in such a way that it would do the wait without the need for a browser.waitForAngular().

Can someone confirm if I need the waitForAngular() in this example?

Answer (score 0):

I think that whether you need browser.waitForAngular() depends on the application you're testing.

Not 100% sure on what the conditions are, but I have found that I required this method when my test is performing a task that requires a response from a server, such as changing a user's password in a web app.

On another note, in my experience, browser.waitForAngular() is not robust enough to handle every type of wait condition I've needed to perform.

For example, I'm writing tests for a web application where the user logs in through a non-Angular page and is directed to an Angular page. If I want to make assertions to test the elements present on the login landing page, I can't  use browser.waitForAngular() because non-angular pages do not have access to this method. I've found that a more reliable way to tell the driver "wait for the page to fully load, then check the text present on the page" is to use [browser.wait](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-webdriver-webdriver-prototype-wait) to explicitly wait for the presence or visibility of an element on the next page that you know will take the longest to load.